# I have working small app that access the camera using intent. The app returns an image captured to an imageview

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I have working small app that access the camera using intent. The app returns an image captured to an imageview. I want to add a functionality to turn that image in imageview to a pdf file. Someone kindly help on how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use itext pdf library. Here is the gradle : `'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.1.1'`

```
Document document=new Document();
 String dirpath=android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(dirpath+"/example.pdf")); //  Change pdf's name.
 document.open();
 Image img =Image.getInstance(dirpath+"/"+"example.jpg");  // Change image's name and extension.

 float scaler = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin()
               - document.rightMargin() - 0) / img.getWidth()) * 100; // 0 means you have no indentation. If you have any, change it.
 img.scalePercent(scaler);
 img.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER | Image.ALIGN_TOP); 
 //img.setAlignment(Image.LEFT| Image.TEXTWRAP); 

 /* float width = document.getPageSize().width() - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin();
 float height = document.getPageSize().height() - document.topMargin() - document.bottomMargin();
 img.scaleToFit(width, height)*/ Or try this.

 document.add(img);
 document.close();
```

Comment: Atif AbbAsi Let me try and get back to you.